# Gazebo Immediately Close on Startup

Tags: ros, gazebo, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am using Ros indigo on Ubuntu 14.04  For some reason I cannot start Gazebo. When I execute gazebo on terminal, it opens the window but after some seconds, it terminates and closes the window. I tried to update Gazebo from 2.2 to 2.2.6 as stated in http://answers.ros.org/question/199401/problem-with-indigo-and-gazebo-22/   I also installed gtk2-engines but none of them worked.
I suspect that it is because of my old graphics card Intel 945GM  but I am not sure.

Here is my terminal output:

```
yusuf@yusuf-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RD870AV-ABA:~$ gazebo
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.6
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.36.54.197
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.6
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.36.54.197
yusuf@yusuf-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RD870AV-ABA:~$
```

Content of my `/usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh`:

```
export GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
export GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-2.2:/usr/share/gazebo_models:${GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH}
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-2.2/plugins:${GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-2.2/plugins
export OGRE_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.8.0
```

Thanks in advance,
Yusuf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248175/gazebo-immediately-close-on-startup/) by [HHH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28539/hhh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found a solution to the problem I mentioned. It may not be the best solution, however. Run the command below before running gazebo

export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1

This resolves the issue with hardware acceleration, but gazebo may work slower depending on your machine

---

Originally posted by [HHH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28539/hhh/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0